# Resizing bootstrap alerts and keeping the 'x' in the right place

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div id="alertmessages"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div class="btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" id="SaveDraft" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="draft_btn_click(this)">Save Draft</button>
            <button type="button" id="RestoreDraft" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="draft_btn_click(this)">Restore Draft</button>
            <button type="button" id="DeleteDraft" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="draft_btn_click(this)">Delete All Drafts</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this javascript to display alert messages when the buttons are clicked, this one is for the save draft button:

```
$('#alertmessages').html
        ('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Your draft has been saved</div>');
```

This is how the alerts display. Larger than the "small" buttons

[image: Alert larger than buttons picture]

I did try overriding the CSS but the `x` button then showed up too far down.

```
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height:30px;
  padding:0px 15px;
}
```

Comment: An executable code snippet will be more easier for others to help you....

Comment: So what do you want to happen? Have the same height for the alert as for your buttons?

Comment: are you sure your screen is at the correct breakpoint? try with `col-5` and `col-7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class `px-2 py-1` to both `.alert` and `.close`, please check the working example below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show px-2 py-1">
        <button type="button" class="close px-2 py-1" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        Your draft has been saved
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="btn-group-sm">
        <button type="button" id="SaveDraft" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="draft_btn_click(this)">Save Draft</button>
        <button type="button" id="RestoreDraft" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="draft_btn_click(this)">Restore Draft</button>
        <button type="button" id="DeleteDraft" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="draft_btn_click(this)">Delete All Drafts</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```